# How to skip first iteration in javascript for-of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, for-of-loop

I know how to skip first iteration in javascript foreach loop

`dataObject.slice(1).forEach((row) => {});`

I want to know how to do the same thing using for of loop in javascript, please help me, thanks

`for( const row of dataObject )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you're skipping it with `forEach` - replace the `dataObject` expression with `dataObject.slice(1)`.

```
for( const row of dataObject.slice(1) )
```

Answer (score 2):

While [CertainPerformace's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70179758/12101554) is what most people, including me, would go with, it does have a the downside of having to make a temporary array copy, which would be bad when you have huge arrays (but completely unnoticeable usually).

To prevent copying the array, create a temporary variable to check if it's the first in the loop. The downsides of this is the temporary variable, and the `if` check on every iteration could make it slower.

```js
let first = true;
for (const row of dataObject) {
  if (first) {
    first = false;
    continue;
  }
  // ... rest of script
}
```

And I would probably just use a traditional incremental for-loop anyways if you want more control over iteration, since `forEach`, `for-of`, and `for-in` are meant to iterate over everything.